# Redirect POST request to another url:port while retaining its data in IIS Server

Tags: redirect, iis, post, url-rewriting, server

I want to redirect the POST request to another url:port with POST data intact but when i am trying to do it IIS server is issuing GET request and losing the data.
The web.config action method is as follows :-

```
<action redirectType="Temporary" type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:7070/site"> </action>
```

Any suggestions.